# What does this symbol (Turkish coat of arms) mean?

Tags: turkey, symbols

Can you tell me what the symbol below means? I would like to know more about it. Tell me everything about every one piece.

[image]

Comment: More context please! What do you already know about this symbol, what have you already been able to find out? Why do you want to know about this? Are there particular parts that you want to ask about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a variant of the [Ottoman Empire's heraldic coat of arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_the_Ottoman_Empire), adopted in 1882.

From Wikipedia:

> It included two flags: the red flag of the Ottoman dynasty with a star and crescent, and the green flag of the Islamic caliph, largely obscured by a cornucopia.
>
> Behind the flags are a number of spears and other weapons.
>
> Hanging beneath the lower flourish are the medals of five of the Ottoman decorations, the depiction of which vary greatly between sources.

I also found an article [here](http://www.yazete.com/gundem/turk-armasi-icin-ilk-adim-812863.html) ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yazete.com%2Fgundem%2Fturk-armasi-icin-ilk-adim-812863.html&edit-text=&act=url), assume that "arming" and "army" are being mistranslated and refer to choosing "arms" in the heraldic sense) which indicates that Turkey has recently (Nov 5th) set up a commission to design new state arms, which it apparently hasn't had since the end of the Ottoman Empire.  Per Google Translate, the article describes the old arms as:

> The famous coat of arms used in the Ottoman Empire was removed by the end of the reign. Arma, also known as the "Ottoman State Order", was founded on April 17, 1882 by Sultan II. It was put into effect by Abdülhamit. From the two banners in the Arma; the "Ottoman dynasty" with the moon-star on the red floor, and the "Islamic caliphate" in the green zone. Libra, "Ottoman justice", books on the balance of the source of justice "Ottoman laws and Kur'an-ı" represented.